# ｃｓｖファイルのアップロードを自動化させたい（RPA）

Tags: python, rpa

検索順位チェックツールの「GRC」というソフトウェアの自動操作を行って、csvファイルのアップロードを自動で行えるようにしたいと思っています。

pythonの「pyautogui」と「pywinauto」ライブラリを使いました。これをタスクスケジューラーに登録して夜間等に定期的に実行をしたいです。

PCの画面を開いている状態でしたら問題なく作動するのですが、画面を開いていない状態だと上手く作動しません。
自分が思うには、両ライブラリとも画面を認識する必要あるからだと思っています。

PCを１日中起動させっぱなしにするなら上記の方法でも出来るのですが、現実的ではありません。

PCが起動していなくても上記の動作を自動化させられる方法は他に何かありませんでしょうか？
pythonで無理そうでしたら、他の方法でも全然大丈夫です。

宜しくお願い致します。

（追記）
AWS(Amazon Work Spaces)の仮想デスクトップサービスの中にWindowsのOSを入れて試してみたのですが、同じくAWSを開いている状態でないと上手く作動しませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

どんな方法であれ、PCが起動していない状態で動作させるのは無理です。

クラウドなどで、サーバーを立てて、定期的に実行させるのが現実的だと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。AWSの方でも試してみたのですが、AWSを開いている状態でないとダメでした。

Comment: AWSでサーバーを立てて、24時間稼働させてタイマー設定する方法が一番いいと思います。
開いている状態というのが、具体的にどのような状態でしょうか？

Comment: AWSのウィンドウを開いている状態です。

Comment: AWSのウィンドウという用語を、存じ上げず申し訳ないです。もし、コンソールのことであれば、閉じていても稼働しているはずですか

Comment: 説明足らずで申し訳ございません。AWS(Amazon Work Spaces)の仮想デスクトップサービスの中にWindowsのOSを入れている状態です。

Comment: 仮想デスクトップだからかと思います。
Amazon Web Services のことを考えていました。
いずれにせよ、常時稼働しているPCがないと上のソフトウェアは動かないと思います。

Comment: なるほど。ご回答ありがとうございました！

Comment: GUI前提で画面起動を前提とするツールを自動実行に使うこと自体向いていない処理です。ファイル転送ならCUI使えそうですが、csvのアップロード先はssh (scp) などの口をもっていないのでしょうか。